# How to display an image in a SharePoint 2010 Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I would like to know how to display a local image in my SharePoint 2010 Web Part. I don't really know which url to write in the css.

Comment: local image in layouts folder or images library?

Comment: I don't actually know where to place it in order to display it in the webpart...I've got the image in a folder "images" in my webpart's folder.  Which is the best way, and how do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. [Add SharePoint "Images" mapped folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx) to the project in Visual Studio.
   [image]
2. Create a `WEB-PART-NAME` folder inside (to keep related images together and not overwrite some other image by accident).
3. Place the image in this folder.
4. Use the following URL: `/_layouts/images/WEB-PART-NAME/IMAGE-FILENAME.png`

Comment: VS creates the project-specifically-named folder for you automatically. When I followed step 1, it creaed an Images folder with a subfolder with the same name as the project.