# How to add resources like images,sound,swf into a sharepoint webpart project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a webpart using visual studio 2010. 
In my project I would like to add some files like images and swf.
These files are there on my system, so how do i add these resources into
the project( and refer them) so that they are packaged and deployed along with the web part ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display an image in a SharePoint 2010 Web Part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121775/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-sharepoint-2010-web-part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps 12-15 of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620532 will show you how to use the mapped folder aspect of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: thanks for answering Mark , do you know any link pointing to how to create custom mapped folders. This is fine if I want to upload images, but how to create a custom mapped folder like swf to upload all the related swfs of the project .

Comment: @deovrat It is not possible to create a custom mapped folder. However, you add the "Images" mapped folder and then create a subfolder inside it. You can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121775/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-sharepoint-2010-web-part/5126897#5126897.